# How to align textview and edittext?

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I have a layout like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_color"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TITLE"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/box_bg" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Text1"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtText1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtText1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Text2"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to align the txtText1 below editText and align the right ide of both views. Align left side of txtText2 with editText. But it seems to be does not work when placing the EditText as center-horizontal.How can i make it ?
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLL"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TITLE" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLL"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/reLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Text2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Text1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```